# Multiple regression with no origin and mix of directly entered and stepwise entered variables using R

Tags: r, stepwise-regression

I am running a regression equation and I want to enter in 12 indepdendent variables then stepwise enter 7 more independent variables and not have an origin.

- DV is `shfl`.
- I  want to enter in the following 12 independent dummy variables
  `ajan
  bfeb
  cmar
  dapr
  emay 
  fjun
  gjul
  haug
  isep
  joct
  knov
  ldec`
- And then I want to enter in a stepwise fashion 
  `slag6
  slag7
  slag8
  slag9
  slag10
  slag11
  slag12`
- And finally, I want there to be no origin.

I've done simple regression, but nothing quite like this that enters in the primary variables and step enters several more.

- How can such a model be specified using R?

Answer (score 7):

I think you can set up your base model, that is the one with your 12 IVs and then use `add1()` with the remaining predictors. So, say you have a model `mod1` defined like `mod1 <- lm(y ~ 0+x1+x2+x3)` (`0+` means *no intercept*), then

```
add1(mod1, ~ .+x4+x5+x6, test="F")
```

will add and test one predictor after the other on top of the base model.

More generally, if you know in advance that a set of variables should be included in the model (this might result from prior knowledge, or whatsoever), you can use `step()` or `stepAIC()` (in the `MASS` package) and look at the `scope=` argument.

Here is an illustration, where we specify a priori the functional relationship between the outcome, $y$, and the predictors, $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{10}$. We want the model to include the first three predictors, but let the selection of other predictors be done by stepwise regression:

```
set.seed(101)
X <- replicate(10, rnorm(100))
colnames(X) <- paste("x", 1:10, sep="")
y <- 1.1*X[,1] + 0.8*X[,2] - 0.7*X[,5] + 1.4*X[,6] + rnorm(100)
df <- data.frame(y=y, X)

# say this is one of the base model we think of
fm0 <- lm(y ~ 0+x1+x2+x3+x4, data=df)

# build a semi-constrained stepwise regression
fm.step <- step(fm0, scope=list(upper = ~ 0+x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7+x8+x9+x10, 
                                lower = ~ 0+x1+x2+x3), trace=FALSE)
summary(fm.step)
```

The results are shown below:

```
Coefficients:
   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
x1   1.0831     0.1095   9.888 2.87e-16 ***
x2   0.6704     0.1026   6.533 3.17e-09 ***
x3  -0.1844     0.1183  -1.558    0.123    
x6   1.6024     0.1142  14.035  < 2e-16 ***
x5  -0.6528     0.1029  -6.342 7.63e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 1.004 on 95 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.814,  Adjusted R-squared: 0.8042 
F-statistic: 83.17 on 5 and 95 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

You can see that $x_3$ has been retained in the model, even if it proves to be non-significant (well, the usual caveats with univariate tests in multiple regression setting and model selection apply here -- at least, its relationship with $y$ was not specified).