# Forcing variable selection to keep certain predictor in R

Tags: stepwise-regression

I am looking for a variable selection technique in R to reduce the number of my regression predictors, where I can force the method to keep a specific variable within the model. Here is a toy example from the R help of ?step, the variable "Examination" will be removed:

```
summary(lm1 <- lm(Fertility ~ ., data = swiss));
slm1 <- step(lm1);
summary(slm1);
```

Comment: This related thread might help: [Multiple regression with no origin and mix of directly entered and stepwise entered variables using R](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9503/multiple-regression-with-no-origin-and-mix-of-directly-entered-and-stepwise-enter).

Comment: (+1) to @chl, nice answer regarding `scope` option (and there is enough information on this pre-selection in `?step`).

Comment: thank you both for your answers! sorry that i missed the information i have been looking for in the R help. best m

Comment: Note that typical variable selection strategies (such as stepwise selection algorithms), which I suspect you have in mind based on the reference to `step()`, are not valid. If that doesn't make sense / you want to know why, you may want to read my answer here: [algorithms-for-automatic-model-selection](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20836//20856#20856).